# javascript resize работает только в одну сторону

Tags: javascript

При уменьшении браузера текст берется из заголовка и добавляется в блок, но при обратном увеличении экрана текст не пропадает. Как сделать чтоб при увеличении текст удалялся?

```js
    function mobText() {

        let mapTitle = document.querySelector(".parking-title h2");
        let mapText = mapTitle.textContent || mapTitle.innerText;
        const mapMobtext = document.querySelector('.parking-map__p');

        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            mapMobtext.innerText = mapText;

        } else (window.innerWidth >= 769); {

        }
    };


    mobText();
    window.addEventListener("resize", mobText);
```

```html
<div class="parking-title">
  <h2>Бесплатная парковка для клиентов</h2>
</div>

<div class="parking-map__p"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не верная запись:

```
} else (window.innerWidth >= 769); {
```

должно быть так:

```
} else {...}
```

или

```
} else if(window.innerWidth >= 769); {...}
```

Можно тут изучить: [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)

В условие можно сделать пустую строку:

```
mapMobtext.innerText = '';
```